# Multiple random NetworkCallbacks (onAvailable) with same networkId from the ConnectivityManager

Tags: java, android, android-connectivitymanager

I don't understand why onAvailable is called multiple times at random moments, the documentation states that it can be called more if the network changes, but the properties of the network object parameter in onAvailable is always the same. I even compared the hashcodes and they are the same...

The problem occurs on my LG lollipop device

Android documentation: (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)

> **onAvailable Added in API level 21** Called when the framework connects and has declared a new
>   network ready for use. This callback may be called more than once if
>   the Network that is satisfying the request changes

EDIT: I have implemented other methods from the callback to check if any other methods are fired (onLosing, onUnavailable, onCapabilitiesChanged, onLinkPropertiesChanged), but none of these are called

I have my own NetworkManager that has this code in it:

```
public void initialize(Context context) {
    connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    setState();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        final NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI).build();

        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(final Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
                Log.d(TAG,"Network is Available. Network Info: " + networkInfo);
                notifyObservers();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLost(final Network network) {
                super.onLost(network);
                notifyObservers();
            }
        });
    } else {
        context.registerReceiver(new NetworkChangeReceiver(), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
Network is Available. Network Info: [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "company_guest", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]
Network is Available. Network Info: [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "company_guest", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]
Network is Available. Network Info: [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "company_guest", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]
Network is Available. Network Info: [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "company_guest", roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]
...
```

Answer (score 3):

We encountered the same issue on the Zebra MC18 devices running Android 5.1. All our other devices, running newer Android versions, do not exhibit this behaviour.

Our workaround was to check if the last onAvailable call came from the same network and we didn't receive onLost for this network in the meantime.

Comment: In my use case, I was connected to a device, then I yanked power from the 'server.'   When power was restored and a new connection attempt was made, onAvailable was invoked 2x, once for each callback registered using requestNetwork method in my connect method.  

To resolve, in onLost callback I unregistered the callback (as if I actually called my disconnect logic).  Fixed me right up.